# How to Display the Prime Numbers in an Array using Scanner Class

Tags: java, arrays, primes

I have recently started learning Java. My school teaches us this weird way that i haven't really seen in many places. I can't find any problems here but the code just won't work. Please point out what is wrong here. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
import java.util.*;
class Prime_array_attempt_infinity
{
    public static void main ()
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        int i, j, counter=0, last;
        int arr[]= new int [10];
        System.out.println("Enter the values");
        for (i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
            arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            last = arr[i];
            for (j=2;j<last;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]%j==0)
                counter++;
                
            }
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]+" is a Prime Number");
           
        }
        }
        
        
    }
            
            
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what your expected and actual results are.

Comment: What weird way does your school teach you with?

Comment: Add `if (last < 2) continue;` and `counter = 0;` after `last = arr[i];`.

Answer (score 0):

Missed `args` for `main` method, and you need to reset `counter` to zero every time before inner for loop( also `1` is not a prime number by definition :)  ):

```
import java.util.*;
class Prime_array_attempt_infinity
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    int i, j, counter=0, last;
    int arr[]= new int [10];
    System.out.println("Enter the values");
    for (i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       
        last = arr[i];
    
        if(last <= 1)continue;

        counter = 0;
        for (j=2;j<last;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]%j==0)
                counter++;

        }
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]+" is a Prime Number");

        }
    }


}


}
```

output:

```
Enter the values
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2 is a Prime Number
3 is a Prime Number
5 is a Prime Number
7 is a Prime Number
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code does not run.

You need to replace your main method with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

And paste all code in it. Like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    int i, j, counter=0, last;
    int arr[]= new int [10];
    System.out.println("Enter the values");
    for (i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        last = arr[i];
        for (j=2;j<last;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]%j==0)
                counter++;

        }
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]+" is a Prime Number");

        }
    }
}
```

Then you are able to run your code snippet. Regarding the algorithm for finding, see e.g. [example algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)